# Google ads API "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client

I get the error :

```
{
  "message": "The caller does not have permission",
  "code": 7,
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com\/google.ads.googleads.v10.errors.GoogleAdsFailure",
      "errors": [
        {
          "errorCode": {
            "authorizationError": "USER_PERMISSION_DENIED"
          },
          "message": "User doesn't have permission to access customer. Note: If you're accessing a client customer, the manager's customer id must be set in the 'login-customer-id' header. See https:\/\/developers.google.com\/google-ads\/api\/docs\/concepts\/call-structure#cid"
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "asds33ad3sdadad334"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the code I get from here : https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/reporting/example

what I need to do with login-customer-id ?

Comment: As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration/login-customer-id), `login-customer-id` needs to be set to the account ID of the manager account (aka MCC) from which you want to access the Ads account in question.

Comment: I do it, and i see the Accounts i added to MCC

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this updated documentation link for anyone who might encounter this same issue:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/concepts/call-structure#cid

You need to add `login-customer-id` to the call and you should use the MCC account ID as the value for this. It is asking for it because the account you want to request is under an MCC account.

[image: MCC account ID]